# Create Docker File for MySQL/Tomcat/Maven Java Webapp

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat, maven-3

how can we create DockerFile for MySQL/Tomcat/Maven project.

Till now i have managed to build DockerFile for spring boot app which has inbuilt tomcat using following code:

```
#FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

#VOLUME /tmp

COPY target/notifier-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /notifier.jar

CMD [ "/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test", "/notifier.jar" ]

#Build command => docker build -f DockerFile -t notifier:latest .
#RUN command => docker run -p 9090:8072 notifier
#Image Path => ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/...

#Save Image Locally => docker save -o notifier.tar notifier
#Load Image Locally => docker load -i notifier.tar notifier
#Run Image Locally => docker run -d --restart=always -p newport:original_port notifier
```

But now i want to use separate mysql/tomcat what changes i need to add to this or any reference resource will be helpful ty.

Answer (score 1):

Use this image, (mysql, tomcat, ant and maven) in Dockerfile

```
From guligo/jdk-maven-ant-tomcat-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use docker-compose.yml with container for each component:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  whatever-other-service:
    image: whateverimage
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and launch using `docker-compose up`

Comment: is this a complete example of what need to be done, i see `whateverimage` text so suspecting it to be incomplete, sorry i an new to Docker

Comment: as far as I understand you have a project that is supported by mysql db. The projects code is behind tomcat server. I'm suggesting one container for mysql, one container for your code behind tomcat

Comment: ok so no need to build a new mysql image, you can build a new image with your code based on one of the images here https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/. after you build the image, change `whatever-other-service` to the name of your service

Comment: also tomcat is not suppose to be preinstalled on destination os/platofrm